# How to rotate Jboss log file in every 3 hour?

Tags: tomcat, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

As per my knowledge to split or rotate jboss log file, we can do that Hourly, Daily, Half-daily, weekly, monthly and Minutely basic.

I want to rotate log file in every 3 hours.Is it possible in jboss-4.2.3GA ? 
If yes then how i can achieve this.

If anybody have any idea please help.

Answer (score 0):

[PeriodicRotatingFileHandler](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/logmanager/handlers/PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java) does not provide any way to rotate log in every 3 hours.